# Issue with user profile and AD synchro

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, user-profile, user-profile-service, synchronisation

I've an issue in my synchro AD with SharePoint 2010.
i've deleted a user from the AD, the synchro runs but i've some web app and on a web app.
If i do check permission, the user exist.
when i select it, i've a sharepoint error that tells me the user is deleted.

If i check in CA, the user profil is not present.

What could it be if the user profil is correctly deleted, the user is deleted from every webapp except on one

Answer (score 0):

Deleted AD users are not removed from site collections. They will be cleaned out of the user profile service and have My sites cleaned up, but they remain in the site collections. This is by design to preserve contextual information like created by fields.

There are tools available to help clean up the user information list and permissions like ControlPoint.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Aren't  there a way to delete  it from powerShell?